# Loop over two lists simultaneously while comparing and storing the result of each loop at each step

Tags: android, kotlin

So, I have two ArrayList of List of Strings

```
var a: ArrayList<List<String>> = arrayListOf(listOf("a", "b"), listOf("d"), listOf("g", "f"), listOf("j"))

var b: ArrayList<List<String>> = arrayListOf(listOf("a", "b"), listOf("c", "d"), listOf("f", "g"), listOf("k"))
```

I want to iterate over ArrayLists a and b simultaneously to get their elements at their index i correspondingly, compare them, and store whether they are equal or not e.g get the first element of a, which is ["a", "b"] and the first element of b which is ["a", "b"]. Check if both these first elements are equal both in size and values inside them (in this case they are equal) and store whether true or false appropriately (in this case, true). Move to the second elements of a and b which is ["d"] and ["c", "d"]. Check if they are also equal (in this case they are not, both in size and values in them) and store the result (in this case, false). Now move to the third elements of a and b which is ["g", "f"] and ["f", "g"]. Are they equal? (in this case yes, both in size and values. Although they are in reverse of each other but still equal). Store the result (in this case, true). And so forth...

So far, I tried using a for loop inside a for loop. The result was disastrous. Not what I wanted at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `zip` function matches up two iterables by their indices. The lambda after it is used to transform the two matched values into what you want in the result List. In this case we just want to see if they are equal. Comparing two lists with `==` compares each of their elements individually, but since you want the order not to matter, you should sort them first to take that out of the comparsion.

```
val result = a.zip(b) { x, y -> x.sorted() == y.sorted() }
```

If the inner lists are very long, you could short circuit the sorting by comparing sizes as well.

```
val result = a.zip(b) { x, y -> x.size == y.size && x.sorted() == y.sorted() }
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Let me try this. If it works as I intend I'll definitely mark this as the correct answer

Comment: How do I do this same thing but for three ArrayList of List of Strings too?

Comment: There’s no zip for three inputs so you could maybe zip a to b, then zip a to c, then zip those two results to each other but with the lambda changed to `x && y` instead of `x.sorted() == y.sorted()`.

Comment: Okay then Thanks. Will try this out